# Replace a old code by a more efficient code

Tags: python, numpy, generator, sequence, logarithm

I need to create a sequence of number `a_t` according to a old sequence of number `z_t` and `a_0`. `a_t` is define equal to `27 if t=0` or `a(t-1)exp(z(t-1)) for t>=1`.

In using generator, that code is simply

```
import math

def a_t(zs, a=27):
    z = next(zs)
    yield a
    for z in zs:
        a *= math.exp(z)
        yield a
```

It seems possible to work with `a_0` only and the sum over `z_t-1, z_t-2, ..., z0` instead of waiting for `a_t-1` to compute `a_t`. So it is possible to vectorize the computation instead of computing the `a_i` one after the other. Is it possible to code the following sequence with `numpy` with purpose of vectorizating, i.e. `a_t = a_0 exp(sum(z_i))` for `i=0 to t-1`? It is probably faster to compute as we already know the sequence `z_t`.

Comment: How do you use this `a_t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

you can use np.cumsum(z) to create a and array with sum(z_i) and np.exp() on that again to calculate what you want, then just multiply that with a_0.

```
a_0 = 27
z = np.array([1,2,3])
cs = np.cumsum(z)
result = np.exp(cs)*a_0
```